# RequestStateChange method invocation throwing an exception

Tags: c#, wmi, ipv6

I am trying to Reset my IPV6 Interface using WMI method RequestStateChange.According to the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/nettcpipprov/msft-netipinterface
Here the RequestStateChange method will change the state of the interface after passing the desired state as an argument.In my case since the action to be done is Reset,I am passing the value 11.But it throws the following exception:
`System.Management.ManagementException: 'This method is not implemented in any class '`
The following is my code that I'm trying to execute.

```
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\StandardCIMV2");

            //create object query
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetIPInterface");

            //create object searcher
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            //get a collection of WMI objects
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            //enumerate the collection.
            foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
            {

                ManagementBaseObject mbo = m.GetMethodParameters("RequestStateChange");
                mbo["RequestedState"] = 11;
                ManagementBaseObject mbo_out = m.InvokeMethod("RequestStateChange",mbo,null);
            }
```

I haven't added the query for an IPV6 interface but I first wanted to get the method and see if it works.I am not really sure where I am going wrong with this.Can someone help with this exception?

Comment: You can't change the properties of a connection after the connection completes.  So I suspect one of the lines is making a connection.  Using from cmd.exe >Netstat -a will show the status of the connections.  So if you step through your code and run Netswtat after each instruction is executed you will be able to tell when the connection is made.

Comment: ManagementScope has an IsConnected property and I can see that the value is true even when the last statement is being executed.I tried calling the create method with another MSFT class MSFT_IPAddress,that works just fine.The issue looks like its with RequestStateChange method and the way I am calling it or something

Comment: When it works are you connected?

Comment: If you are asking if the IsConnected property is set to true,it is in the working case

Comment: Even in the non-working case it is set to true

Comment: You may not have access to this info.  Are you an Admin?  Try starting VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Then see if you get same error.